# Generic Compound Types in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have the generic types `A<T>` and `B<T>` and now I want to construct the type `C<T> : A<B<T>>` which as you can see is a very specific kind of `A<T>`.

It tried defining `C` just like that but I get

```
The type `A<B<T>>' does not contain a constructor that takes `0' arguments
```

Just in case I built the constructor

```
public C () {}
```

but I still get the error.

**Note:** This is an abstraction of the problem. Assume that A and B have a constructor with the form

```
public A/B (T t)
```

Comment: What is the constructor of `A`?

Comment: You need to provide more code showing what you're trying to do.

Comment: `B`'s constructor isn't important with your definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generic type declaration is okay, but your parameterless constructor doesn't have a counterpart in `A<T>`.

You should call the base class' constructor with the parameters it requires.

Something like:

```
public C() : base("param1", "param2", 3)
{
}
```